# Discord.py: change server name

Tags: discord.py

How can I change the server name? I'm trying that code but I get an error( TypeError: edit() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given)

```
await ctx.guild.edit(ctx.guild.name, None, "New name")
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the [API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.edit) your second parameter is not necessary, because the default value for reason is already none.

Try either

```
await ctx.guild.edit("New name")
```

or try to append your value to the needed keys in the dict **fields, like:

```
await ctx.guild.edit(name="New name")
```

and other parameters from the available one if necessary.